# Git reset --hard And some problems with history

Tags: git

I used git reset --hard HEAD command to go back a commit from 1-2months back.
all is ok and it works well but I have a small problem I try many ways with another commands to fix this but I don't know really ( or maybe It is not possible at all ) please guide me

What is the problem?
lets say I have 5 commit , and all of them are pushed already to GitHub ( it is saved in both GitHub and local )

```
6de7a0b8797652812da68cb537069aae96ca4939
ff77741a61a6b272aed43135036e035b2ff82986
45c857a6bf78f7913ad4032524c84df41b7efc5f
9ad79934d3f1e33488dde2959dfad6fa80094e1d
98fb5dc9bcf1ded8a07e1a44c090e31640dad0ff
```

now I used git reset --hard to go back 9ad79934d3f1e33488dde2959dfad6fa80094e1d commit , now reset works well and my files are true. but my problem is I want to remove these three commits

```
6de7a0b8797652812da68cb537069aae96ca4939
ff77741a61a6b272aed43135036e035b2ff82986
45c857a6bf78f7913ad4032524c84df41b7efc5f
```

from my local ( from the history ) and I don't want to push it to GitHub , only remove it from my computer history

is there any way to do this?

tnx

Comment: in my case 98fb5dc9bcf1ded8a07e1a44c090e31640dad0ff this commit is highlighted to black, but others aren't highlighted.

Comment: and this only happen when the commits are pushed already in GitHub. it means when I use local and if I use git reset it will be vanished for ever . but pulls from GitHub aren't same as local

Answer (score 0):

You can try `git rebase -i SHA` ("interactive rebase") and then just `drop` the commits you want to remove. Nevertheless I am not sure why would you like to diverge local and remote?

I suggest you not to diverge and to checkout to a branch locally from the commit you're trying to revert to:

```
git checkout 9ad7993
git checkout -b your-branch-name
```